# Hierarchical time series prediction using Fourier for xreg and newxreg

Tags: r, regression, fft, hierarchical-data, arima

I want to use xreg = Fourier(ts, k,f) as regressor in a hierarchical time series.

I can get the regressor to work for a single series.

I have a hierarchical time series, hts, that is composed of series similar to the first one (same number of time-steps).

Reference for hts:  https://robjhyndman.com/publications/hierarchical-tourism/

I am getting error on the forecast from the hts using the same regressor. What is the problem?

**train_ts:  entire hts, of the form visnights.

top_ts    :     just the top level time series**

When done for a single series,  top_ts , using xreg and newxreg works.

```
KK <- 12
REG= fourier(top_ts,KK,52)

model <- auto.arima(top_ts, xreg=fourier(top_ts, K=KK))
fcstResult <- forecast(model, h=1, xreg= REG, newxreg=REG)
```

WORKS

When I do prediction for  hts similar to visnights, train_ts,

```
train_ts <- window(vis_ts, c(2,1), end= c(3, 52))

fcstResult <- forecast(train_ts, h=1, fmethod="arima", method = "bu")
```

WORKS

When I use the same regressor XREG on the hts, it errors:

```
fcstResult <- forecast(
  train_ts, h = 1, method = "bu", fmethod = "arima", xreg=REG, newxreg=REG)

OR

fcstResult <- forecast(
  train_ts, h = 1, method = "bu", fmethod = "arima", xreg=REG, newxreg=REG, lambda=0)



Error in model.frame.default(formula = x ~ xregg, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) :
  variable lengths differ (found for 'xregg')
```

(I made all columns nonzero and added a small random noise, so that  is not the problem)

Comment: Per `r` tag (hover to see): Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code chunk, the `newxreg` argument is ignored, and so is the `h` argument. The values of `REG` are taken to be the required regressors for future time periods. If your training data has length equal to a multiple of 52 this will coincidentally be correct due to the periodicity of Fourier terms, but it is better to be explicit like this:

```r
library(hts)
vis_ts <- hts(fpp2::visnights, characters = c(3, 5))
train_ts <- window(vis_ts, end=c(2010,4))
test_ts <- window(vis_ts, start=c(2011,1))
train_top <- aggts(train_ts, level=0)
test_top <- aggts(test_ts, level=0)
train_reg <- fourier(train_top, K=2)
test_reg <- fourier(test_top, K=2)

model <- auto.arima(train_top, xreg=train_reg)
fcstResult <- forecast(model, xreg=test_reg)
```

When using the hierarchical approach, both an `xreg` and a `newxreg` argument need to be passed corresponding to the training and test periods. In this function, the rows of `newxreg` are checked to ensure they match the value of `h`. This is causing an error.

The following code will work

```r
fcast_hts <- forecast(train_ts, method='bu', fmethod='arima', 
  xreg=train_reg, newxreg=test_reg)
```